# How do I generate a random sample of groups, including all people in the group, where the group_id (but not the person_id) changes across time?

Tags: postgresql, random

I have data that looks like this:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+------+
| group_id | person_id | is_primary | year |
+----------+-----------+------------+------+
| aaa1     |         1 | TRUE       | 2000 |
| aaa2     |         1 | TRUE       | 2001 |
| aaa3     |         1 | TRUE       | 2002 |
| aaa4     |         1 | TRUE       | 2003 |
| aaa5     |         1 | TRUE       | 2004 |
| bbb1     |         2 | TRUE       | 2000 |
| bbb2     |         2 | TRUE       | 2001 |
| bbb3     |         2 | TRUE       | 2002 |
| bbb1     |         3 | FALSE      | 2000 |
| bbb2     |         3 | FALSE      | 2001 |
+----------+-----------+------------+------+
```

The data design is such that

1. `person_id` uniquely identifies an individual across time
2. `group_id` uniquely identifies a group within each year, but may change from year to year
3. each group contains primary and non-primary individuals

My goal is three-fold:

1. Get a random sample, e.g. 10%, of primary individuals
2. Get the data on those primary individuals for all time periods they appear in the database
3. Get the data on any non-primary individuals that share a group with any of the primary individuals that were sampled in the first and second steps

I'm unsure where to start with this, since I need to first pull a random sample of primary individuals and get all observations for them. Presumably I can do this by generating a random number that's the same within any `person_id`, then sample based on that. *Then*, I need to get the list of `group_id` that contain any of those primary individuals, and pull all records associated with those `group_id`.

I don't know where to start with these queries and subqueries, and unfortunately, the interface I'm using to access this database can't link information across separate queries, so I can't pull a list of random `person_id` for primary individuals, then use that text file to filter `group_id` in a second query; I have to do it all in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to get this done is:

```
select
  data_result.*
from
  data as data_groups join
  (select
     person_id
   from
     data
   where
     is_primary
   group by
     person_id
   order by
     random()
   limit 1) as selected_primary
   ON (data_groups.person_id = selected_primary.person_id)
   JOIN data AS data_result ON (data_groups.group_id = data_result.group_id AND data_groups.year = data_result.year)
```

I even made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/05fd4/5/0) so you can test it.

The query is pretty straightforward, it gets the sample, then it gets their groups and then it gets all the users of those groups.

Please pay atention to the Limit 1 clause that is there because the data set was so little. You can put a value or a query that gets the right percentage.

If anyone has an answer using windowing functions I'd like to see that.

Note: next time please provide the schema and the data insertion so it is easier to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. How would I tweak this to alias the table name (`data`) to something shorter? In the actual database, the table name is significantly longer. Otherwise I think this works and I'll accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: Will this account for the fact that the `group_id` can change each year? I think it does, based on the fiddle, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Is it even possible to alias the `data` table name to something else, so that if I only want to select certain variables from the table in the first `select` statement (instead of `select data.*`), I don't have to include the full (long) table name in the actual query more than once?

Comment: You can alias the name of the table on each from clause but I don't think you can make a single alias. So in the case of this query you'll have to write it 3 times. I'll edit the post to show this and to take into account the year.